# Tsunami of molten rocks

Tags: technological-development, aliens, construction

**1. Setting**

A planet half the size of Jupiter with the entire surface covered with molten rocks and lava found to orbit a binary star system in close proximity.

**2. Objective**

Erect a 2000m(L) X 2000m(W) X 400m(H) Hi-Tech building at least 500m from sea level in the middle of ocean of molten rock and lava.

**3. Purpose**

Set up a automated prison with a maximum capacity of 200,000 aliens from every part of the galaxy. (the idea is that should things go nasty, this hi-tech building will automatically cut off its power and doom all the prisoners into the abyss of hell literally)

**4. Problem**

i. A building this size to hover over a seemingly endless ocean of molten rocks and lava is technologically challenging especially the mechanism to maintain its altitude.

ii. Occasionally a mega tsunami of molten rocks and lava as tall as 1000m pose a serious threat to the building as well as the inmates.

**5. Question**

How do I construct a floating prison that could withstand a mega tsunami?

Comment: Maybe it couldn't.  If it floats, the simplest way to avoid it would simply be to move higher or far away from the tsunami.

Comment: It wouldn't take any more energy to hover 1500m above the surface than it would to hover at 500m, so why not just hover higher?

Comment: I intended to locate this supermax as close as possible to the pits of purgatory muhahahaha... Imagine the conversation between inmates: "damn it this is hotter than hell... I sure going to turn over a new leaf when I get out!".

Comment: And you probably want us to ignore the problem of the crushing gravity?

Comment: @DJMethaneMan Crushing gravity factor it in, Jovian's surface gravity is 24.79 m/s² and Gaia's is 9.807 m/s². if a person with mass of 100 Kg on Earth will weight 100 Kg x 9.807 m/s² = 980.7 N (avg human bite is 720 N) and on this ball of burning passion assuming g = 20 m/s² so s/he  will weight 100 Kg x 20 m/s² = 2000 N (still lose to bite of american alligator of 9000 N) of course the pressure there will be at least 1 MPa (ten times a human bite and that's nasty) lol.

Comment: In regards to the tsunami...does this imply this magma ocean has particular depths and shores through out it?  A tsunami in open 'water' is pretty much undetectable (a 1km high tsunami when the depth of water is 5km is barely noticeable)...it's when this 1km wave is in 100m deep water that it looks like the wave we know.  So...is there a 'ocean floor' and costal regions to your lack of magma?  And one other note...half the size of jupiter and rocky will have a bigger mass than the hydrogen filled jupiter and therefore a higher gravity than jupiter not less.  Do you me half mass or half size?

Comment: @Twelfth this planet is inspired by [CoRoT-7b](http://www.space.com/7782-strange-lava-world-shriveled-remains.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of hovering, how about actually floating on the surface of the molten ocean?

I say this not just because I can, but it might be a viable option. The only requirement for anything to float is for its density to be lower than that of the stuff it's floating in. In this case, we're floating things on molten rock, which has a very high density.

If you use modern, light, strong, low-density materials to construct your prison building, then you have a large, low density structure which could viably float on the surface.

It would avoid the tsunami of molten rock simply because of the structure of a tsunami. Tsunami are not classic wave shape: in the deep ocean, they are shaped a bit like a Bell curve (normal distribution curve). Although it is a rather large tsunami we're talking about here, the base will be wider and the gradient of the curve's side much the same. Like a boat, your prison building could simply ride up and over the wave, remaining completely undisturbed.

Answer (score 2):

Why not make it a Under-magma facility on the bottom, or just put it underground with a submarine floating to the surface for prisoner intake.

Not just that the prisoners could do chores such as mine ore from under the facility, tend to hydro/aeroponic gardens which could support the facility halfway.

And when something *might* go wrong the energy is cut out which would keep them at the bottom of *hell*.

Comment: The extreme heat intensifies (along with pressure) the farther you go down. Eventually you will reach a point where the station simply melts.

Answer (score 1):

## Space elevator?

> The prison finally came into view over the molten horizon. From deep within the inferno below sprouted a thick, twisting pillar rising up towards the penitentiary. As the prisoners' gaze shifted above, another object shifted into their vision. Wrapped around the tendril was a cylindrical building with multiple, asymmetric protrusions. At the center lied rows after rows of spiked rollers desperately clinging to the pillar's altitude. Further above, an incredible mass somehow kept the entire structure above the fiery turmoil.
>
> As the transport descended, a large rumble began to deeply concern the new inmates. The entire prison was slowly rotating upwards with growing velocity to meet its next meal.